# Global and Local costmap configuration

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new  to ROS and was reading about the global and local costmap configuration here http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup.

I noticed that the static map parameter is set to true in global_costmap configuration while it is set to false in the local costmap configuration. Can somebody explain this to me ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395107/global-and-local-costmap-configuration/) by [Sid05](https://answers.ros.org/users/94909/sid05/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2022-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some relevant info: https://answers.ros.org/question/10620/whats-the-difference-between-global-and-local-costmaps-static_map/

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2022-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sid05](https://answers.ros.org/users/94909/sid05/) on 2022-04-21**:
Thanks for pointing it out